# Ошибка с модулем pyowm

Tags: python, pyowm

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('240b25078b2feec50d1e6a658e9a010b')

place = input(">> ")

observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.get_weather()
print(w)
```

Текст ошибки:

```
'OWM' object has no attribute 'weather_at_place'
```

И почему-то выводит ошибку

Comment: Ошибку выводит:'OWM' object has no attribute 'weather_at_place'

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо использовать **weather_manager**. 
Попробуйте так:

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('240b25078b2feec50d1e6a658e9a010b')

place = input(">> ")

mgr = owm.weather_manager()

observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.get_weather
print(w)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в python-консоли:

```
dir(owm:=<созданный обьект owm>) # выдает методы обьекта
```

Найдите что то похожее на weather_at_place,может имя метода в данной версии изменилось.А так говорит что метод с таким именем не закодирован(не существует).